# Asp.net controls to avoid when developing for mobile phones

Tags: asp.net, controls, mobile-website

Are there any guidelines regarding which asp.net controls (e.g. GridView, UpdatePanel...?) should be avoided when developing a web application for mobile phones?

My application is going to be used probably in iphone, blackberry or android enabled phone, so I would like to know if there are known problems related, for example, to control renderization or javascript handling in these platforms' mobile browsers.

Also, usability guidelines regarding best controls to avoid / use would also be appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to targeting different mobile browsers (Modernizr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point there is no Web Forms project template for mobile in ASP.NET Web Forms but there is in the new MVC release:

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

Here's some info on creating mobile pages for Web Forms:

[How To: Add Mobile Pages to Your ASP.NET Web Forms / MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application)

Lastly, you might want to consider using [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/).

As for controls to avoid? Definitely the richer ones like Calendar and GridView - but jQuery Mobile can offer you some options for the former...

You can use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) for feature detection to better target specific mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking:

1. That the generated pages validate on http://validator.w3.org/ - depending on which version of ASP.NET you're using, some of the controls throw out some bad HTML.
2. Depending on what you're doing, the GridView control may not render too well on small screens
3. Have a look at media queries to use different CSS styling for smaller screens

The first thing though could be to just try it out. Get the devices and visit a site that you know uses the controls and see what it's like. If you've not started on the site yet, consider using ASP.NET MVC to ensure that you're writing good HTML. You can use jQuery to do the ajax calls.

Comment: HTML5 will not validate right now... just a heads-up. I would use the ListView for cleaner HTML...